# Is that wordpress don't use php session?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a wordpress blog . and I found that the **session.save_path=/tmp** option in php.ini seems not working : when I logged into my blog site , no session file created under /tmp .
And I also do a grep for 'session_start' keyword under wordpress directory , and shows nothing.

```
bob@wordpress:/data/blog/ailms.me$ ls
favicon.ico                  readme.html         wp-comments-post.php  wp-cron.php        wp-login.php         wp-signup.php
googleab56ac87e653051f.html  wp-activate.php     wp-config.php         wp-includes        wp-mail.php          wp-trackback.php
index.php                    wp-admin            wp-config-sample.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-settings.php      xmlrpc.php
license.txt                  wp-blog-header.php  wp-content            wp-load.php        wp-settings.php.bak
bob@wordpress:/data/blog/ailms.me$ 
bob@wordpress:/data/blog/ailms.me$ grep session_start * -r -l
bob@wordpress:/data/blog/ailms.me$
```

Is that means the wordpress do **NOT** use php session  ?

Comment: Apparently not. Nobody forces it to.

Comment: Actually I don't know why this question is closed as off topic . I'm a newbie to PHP , and I thinks this question is about PHP , so I posted it here , not the 'Super User'

Comment: More info [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-does-wordpress-handle-sessions-and-session-variables) and [here](http://www.pengzhang.ca/blog/2011/03/21/wordpress-does-not-use-session/) from this [trivial search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=does+wordpress+use+sessions%3F). Please always search for questions before you ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doesn't use sessions. It stores authentication information in a cookie, and user/session-related preferences in a user meta table.

Comment: Sooo... it uses *database based sessions...!?*

Comment: @deceze: In a sense, yes, if you consider the session to last forever and to be picked up where you left it when you out and back in.